# Is it possible to create a link to a csv version of a spreadsheet in Microsoft Onedrive?

Tags: onedrive, office365

Using google docs I can link straight to a CSV feed of a shared spreadsheet, and access this programmatically, without authentication. Is this possible with Microsoft Onedrive?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this directly with OneNote. You can set up an unauthenticated link but to present a CSV you will need to save as CSV from the spreadsheet. This could be done with a macro if you need to partially automate it.